# How to return to previous position in a line? How to CTRL-O in a line?

Tags: cursor-movement

After pressing `0` in a line, how can I now jump back to where I just was?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

Unless you left a mark there before pressing `0`, in which case you can do `` `<mark> `` to move the cursor back:

```
m'0``
```

See `:help marks`.